# Are the weekly numbers on my dashboard calculating data from the past week or up to the next week?

Tags: keen-io

Are the 83 signups showing for March 18th calculating the signups between March 11 - March 18 or are these the number of signups that happened from March 18 - March 25?

[Screenshot of dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leLZD.png)

Comment: We have no way of knowing the meaning of this chart or the underlying data based on just a screenshot.  Do you have a data source query you can provide?

Comment: The dashboard is set to show a "this_3_months" timeframe of signups on a site set to show at weekly intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Gotcha, thanks for the screenshot of your analysis run on the [Keen IO](https://keen.io?s=stackoverflow) Explorer. You have a weekly interval, combined with a "this_3_months" timeframe.  The "this" timeframes are inclusive of the current time, so this is going to be "up till right now".  This, means that the final datapoint on the chart is the current week (which is still in progress).  The result for that number is going to keep growing if new data comes in.  And once you leave this week, and start a new week, that will be the second to last data point.  Only when that happens, will that datapoint be unchanging.

Here's a link to more information about using timeframes in Keen. There's a chart which describes how you can use relative timeframes like 'this' or 'previous' here: [chart](https://keen.io/docs/api/#relative-timeframes).